# Trouble with using a static method in a very simple hello world PHP program

Tags: php, zend-framework, static

I'm learning by reading this tutorial: [Link](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/a.not.so.simple.hello.world.tutorial)
Here's the code:

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    public static $root = '';
    public static $frontController = null;

    public static function run(){
        self::setupEnvironment();
        self::prepare();
        $response = self::$frontController->dispatch();
        self::sendResponse($response);
    }

    public static function setupEnvironment(){
        error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors',true);
        ini_set('display_errors',true);
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        self::$root = realpath('..');
        define('APP_ROOT', self::$root);
        spl_autoload_register(array(__CLASS__,'autoload'));

    }
}

?>
```

I'm recieving this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot make non static method Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap::run() static in class Bootstrap in C:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\HelloWorld\application\Bootstrap.php on line 6

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look carefully the error says it all:

**Cannot make** non static method Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap::**run() static**

So remove the static modifier from the run method def.

Comment: But the tutorial says the run() method has to be static, what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing  `public static function run(){`  to    `public function run(){`

Answer (score 0):

A method can only be invoked statically if

1. it is defined as being static,
2. it makes no reference to any non-static declaration

This is because static functions are run without any context which makes them (marginally) quicker than standard methods, but with some constraints. See [PHP Manual for Static keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

In the code, the class Bootstrap declares run() as static, but it is overloading a method run() from the parent class Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap.

If you look at the code for the parent class, you will that its function run() is not declared to be static. Since overloaded methods must match the declaration of their parent method, this means you cannot declare (or invoke) BootStrap::run() as static.

The solution is to modify your code to remove the static declaration.

```
public function run(){
    self::setupEnvironment();
    self::prepare();
    $response = self::$frontController->dispatch();
    self::sendResponse($response);
}
```

I don't use Zend, so not sure if you'll just run into further static related errors as a result. Fundamentally, check your code versus the tutorial, and if it matches then follow another tutorial; that one must be wrong.